# Examining the Zav

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, midrash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, inspection

Does anyone know of any rabbinic sources (Talmudic/midrashic) that indicate that a [*Zav*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zav) would go to a halakhic authority to be examined regarding his *Zivah*?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking for a written text to consult, or a live person?

Comment: Examined for what purpose?

Comment: Is [Mishna Zavin 2:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91#.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.91) what you are looking for?